# How to create custom button Ask seller Ebay

Tags: javascript, html, ebay-design-templates

I am creating a new custom selling page for my shop and I would like to create a button: "Ask a seller a question". I have been Googling around, but unfortunately, I couldn't find much about it. Can anyone please share advice? The one thing I found that may work: this script; but to be honest (as I am very much a beginner), I am not sure how to link a button.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
for (i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++)
{
    if (document.links[i].search.indexOf("ShowCoreAskSellerQuestion") > 0)
    {
        document.write('<a href="'+document.links[i].href+'" title="ask a question">Ask seller a question</a>');
        break; 
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the button to do? Do you want to navigate to a new page, or do you want something pop up?

Comment: Try using jQuery. You can do this with it. The button link is just a normal image, with a link the fires on-click.

Comment: the button has to navigate to the ebay question form ...something like :[link] ( http://contact.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ShowSellerFAQ&iid=&requested=My-shop-name&redirect=0&frm)[/link]

Comment: @user2482756 assuming `document.links[i].href` has the proper URL the `href` attribute will allow the user to navigate to the question form. Now you may need to add some CSS to make the the `<a>` look like a button.

Comment: Ty BrianM , please can you be so kind to make easy example for the css , so I can work around it ( as said before I don't really know how to link it )

Comment: how can I call the script function to the link or images ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript you have will work, but it will only show up as a link. To make is look like a button you will need to add some CSS. [Here](http://www.cssbasics.com/) you can read up on how it works. Essentially CSS will tell the HTML, or in your case the `<a>` how to look. Give the tag an an id `<a id="some-name">` then in your CSS do this:

```
#some-name{
    background: url("yourImagePath") no-repeat;
    height: [the height in pixels of the image] 
}
```

This easiest thing for you would be to find a button image and add to the CSS.